# Using tikz with \pause command in rmarkdown or quarto presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, r, pause, rmarkdown

I'm trying [quarto](/questions/tagged/quarto) for my slides and wondering how to use `\pause` in [tkiz](/questions/tagged/tkiz) code. Minimum working example (`Test.qmd`) is below for reference.

````
---
title: "Test Slides"
format:
  revealjs: 
    chalkboard: 
      buttons: false
    preview-links: auto
    css: styles.css
---

## Intro
Here is a TikZ picture

```{r, engine = 'tikz'}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
 %\pause
 \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Using `\pause` inside a tikzpicture is not the best of ideas. This can cause other problems, like missing footlines.

Instead, I suggest to use the `overlay-beamer-styles` library:

````
---
title: "Test Slides"
format: beamer
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tikz}
  - \usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
---

### Intro

Here is a TikZ picture

```{=latex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[visible on=<2->] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

[image]

Comment: This works fine for `beamer` format. Wondering if there is any solution for `revealjs` format.

Answer (score 0):

[image: mwe]

````
---
title: "Test Slides"
format: beamer
---

### Intro

Here is a TikZ picture

```{=latex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\pause
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````